# JavaFX, Рисование на Canvas

Tags: java, javafx

Как рисовать на одном Canvas из разных классов? Проблема в том, что при обращении к canvas из разных классов возвращаются разные ссылки.

Главный класс, загружающий приложение:

```
@FXML
public Canvas game = new Canvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
//Объект для взаимодействия с классом.
public static GameController gamecontroller = new GameController();
//Графический контекст, из которого я рисую
public GraphicsContext gc = this.getGraphicsContext();
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    System.out.println("Game was loaded");
    gc = getGraphicsContext(); //{return draw.getGraphicsContext2D;}
    gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    gc.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    Handler.handler.addGameObject(new Player(30.0, 30.0, Id.player)); //Добавляю объект на сцену
    Handler.handler.render(); //Рисую его
}
public GraphicsContext getGraphicsContext()
{
    return game.getGraphicsContext2D();
}
```

Также у меня есть класс GameObject, от которого наследуются классы игровых объектов, Player, например.
GameObject:

```
public static GraphicsContext draw
        = GameController.gamecontroller.getGraphicsContext();
```

Player:

```
public void render() {
    draw.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    draw.fillRect(10,10,16,16);
}
```

То есть метод render() работает, но на Canvas ничего не отображается, почему-то при обращении к одному объекту (или при обращении к функции, которая возвращает значение), возвращаются разные ссылки на него.

Comment: А что за геттер `getGraphicsContext()`? Его покажете?

Comment: public GraphicsContext getGraphicsContext()
    {
        return game.getGraphicsContext2D();
    }

Comment: Так. Код главного класса, который вы показали, находится в классе `GameController `, верно? Вероятно проблема в том, что у вас два экземпляра `GameController`. Где-то создается один, вызывается его метод `initialize`. А в статическую переменную `gamecontroller` записывается новый экземпляр. И из-вне вы обращаетесь к новому экземпляру. Если это так, то оставьте это неинициализированным `public static GameController gamecontroller;`, а в `initialize` допишите строчку `gamecontroller = this`. Если все дело в этом, то добавлю ответом.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Несколько дней на это убил:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, у вас получается несколько экземпляров класса `GameController`. Вы создаете первый где-то при старте своего приложения, вызываете его метод `initialize`. Тот, в свою очередь, вызывает `render` на объекте `Player`, а `render` читает статическое поле `gamecontroller`. А поле `gamecontroller` инициализировано другим экземпляром `GameController`. Вот и получается, что вы обращаетесь к совсем другому объекту.

Попробуйте исправить свой код так:

```
...
public static GameController gamecontroller; // оставьте это поле неинициализированным
...

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    ....
    gamecontroller = this; // пусть теперь это поле ссылается на созданный вами экземпляр GameController
    ...
}
```

Если ваш код нигде больше не дергает `GameController.gamecontroller` до инициализации поля, то `NullPointerException` не вылетит и все будет замечательно.